# How do I get estimates, SE, and z and p-values for variables in top model in a GLMM (MuMIn package)?

Tags: r, summary

I am running a GLMM (package: MuMIn) with a dependent variable with a gaussian distribution and several fixed effect variables and a random effect.  For my other analyses, I've been averaging the top models (delta AICc < 3) then extracting the estimates, SE, and z- and p-values for each of the fixed effects. However, there is only one model with a delta AICc < 3 so I just want to extract the estimates, SE, z-, p-values from this top model.

```
Glucose1=glmer(GlucoseCon~Species.f * Treatment.f * Age+(1|NestID.f),GlucoseFile,gaussian)
Glucose2<-dredge(Glucose1,trace=TRUE,rank=AICc,extra="r.squaredGLMM")
```

What I've been using to average the top models:

```
attr(Glucose2,"rank.call") 
Glucose3<- get.models(Glucose2,1:8)
summary(model.avg(Glucose3))
```

BUT for the top model only, how do I get the Estimates, SE, and z- and p-values for Species, Treatment, Age, and their interactions?

There must be an easy code for this but none of my friends seem to know what it is. Yes, I've tried `summary(model)` and it only gives me the mean, median, etc. for all the models.

Comment: any chance of a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) ?  I

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
topmod <- get.models(Glucose2, 1))
topmod(gm1)$coefficients
```

or, if you care to calculate p-values by hand:

```
coefTable(Glucose2)[[1]]
```